# IIS Rewrite ARR sub folders and main site on root URL

Tags: regex, http, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I might just be missing something small.

I have several sites that I have set up with ARR and they work except for the base URL which should still continue to point to the legacy app.

It should resolve to the following:

- [www.mysite.com/app1](http://www.mysite.com/app1)  --> App1
- [www.mysite.com/app2](http://www.mysite.com/app2)  --> App2
- [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)      --> Legacy App (**Not working**)

I understand that the rewrite rules are check in the order that it is placed, therefore I placed the legacy app last. I figure my matching URL regex is suspect.

Is this even possible? Would appreciate the help so much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to App1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app1/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://pc1.local/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to App2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app2/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://pc2.local/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Legacy App" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://legacypc.local/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>                
                <rule name="Add STS headers to HTTPS response">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Ensure secure Cookies" preCondition="Missing secure cookie">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="Missing secure cookie">
                        Don't remove the first line here, it does do stuff!
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can easily observe if anything is wrong via FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you request url `www.mysite.com/`, it is considered as directory, so it doesn't match the condition `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />`.

If there aren't any directories when your application running, I think you can remove the second condition `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />` in "**Reverse Proxy to Legacy App**" rule directly. And then it can implement your requirement.